# Most Captures Chess

Tags: chess, optimization, checkerboard, construction

In Most Captures Chess puzzle, you will need to provide a legal game where it is Blacks to play and where they have the most different ways to capture a White piece.

For instance, the next game allows two ways for Blacks to capture a White piece.

> **1.** e4 d5
> **2.** c4

[image]

How many ways will you reach?

Comment: Just to clarify: any different black piece can take any different white piece, or something must be fixed? I mean, the roughest estimate would be 16x16 for a possibility of every piece taking every other piece? e4 d5 confused me, since it probably should be other way round.

Comment: @ThomasBlue, yes a quite large bound for the optimal solution is 16x16 where ideally, all blacks could eat all white pieces. It's not a possible solution obviously

Comment: e4 d5, then c4 is only one solution for the puzzle, you could start with a total other opening. It was only to show a solution of value 2 which is very far from an optimal one :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you would show possibilities for the black's turn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per stolen from [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8323/maximum-number-of-captures-in-a-position) CSE question, the known record, as standing for 53 years so far, is **74 captures for one side.** *The color is irrelevant, as it can easily be switched.*

**T. W. Marlow & William Cross, Problem 05/1967**

> [image]

**Beat that!**

Answer (score 6):

> 71
>  [image]
>  48 pawn moves (each has two times four different promotions;
>  15 knight moves;
>  5 queen moves;
>  3 king moves

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but is there a reason black gave up its bishops and rooks?  Seems like you could squeeze in a few more potential captures if you added them back in...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It most likely has to do with the fact that the position must be reachable in a game. I'm pretty sure you need to sacrifice pieces to allow white promote their pawns without disturbing black's pawns

Comment: Exactly, I think getting all the pawns past each other costs a minimum of 6 pieces.

Comment: I don't know if it's reachable yet, but if the knight on e3 were a pawn on h2 it would count one more.

Comment: Like Paul said, not enough captures. You need 8 here: 6 to get the pawns in place and 2 for the knight promotions.

Comment: @EphraimRuttenberg Okay, but if black gave up 2 pawns instead of its bishops, say the c2 and f2 pawns could be bishops instead, giving you 2 more attacks on those rooks - I guess that would only improve the count if you didn't consider each different promotion of a pawn, even if it's on the same square, to be a different move.

Answer (score 2):

I know people would come here soon to make better estimates, but let's say **18**.

> Moving all pawns to the middle line, then knights one by one (then some placeholder turn by the whites) we have 14 options for eating a pawn with a pawn and 4 more options for eating a pawn with a knight.

I don't attach a picture, for this is rather obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is possible for 14 times 4 + 13 = 69 captures

> [image]

after e.g. this intermediate position where white has captured the bishops

> [image]

Comment: You probably want to replace the d1 Q and the d5 R with pieces that do not pin d2 and d4.

Comment: You are right, and f1 and a8 are also a problem  :-(  I will move some pieces around to correct